# write method in spring batch not called

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

I have a problem whereby the write method is not called.

Spring Context

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
">

<!-- spring batch context -->
<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<!-- Must set this -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobRegistry"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />

<!-- spring batch context -->

<bean id="report" class="core.Report" scope="prototype" />

<bean id="customWriter" class="spring.jobs.CustomWriter" />

<batch:job id="reportJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="cvsFileItemReader" writer="customWriter"
                commit-interval="10">
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="cvsFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">

    <!-- Read a csv file -->
    <property name="resource" value="file:input/report.csv" />

    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names" value="id,impressions" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
                    <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="report" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>

<!-- run every 5 seconds -->
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <bean id="cronTrigger"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
            <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail" />
            <property name="cronExpression" value="*/5 * * * * ?" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jobDetail"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="quartz.JobLauncherDetails" />
    <property name="group" value="quartz-batch" />
    <property name="durability" value="true" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="jobName" value="reportJob" />
            <entry key="jobLocator" value-ref="jobRegistry" />
            <entry key="jobLauncher" value-ref="jobLauncher" />
            <entry key="param1" value="j1" />
            <entry key="param2" value="j2" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

CustomWriter.java

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;

import core.Report;

public class CustomWriter implements ItemWriter<Report> {

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Report> items) throws Exception{

        System.out.println("writer..." + items.size());
        for(Report item : items){
            System.out.println(item);
        }

    }
}
```

quartz.JobLauncherDetails class

```
package quartz;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.JobLocator;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;

public class JobLauncherDetails extends QuartzJobBean {

    static final String JOB_NAME = "jobName";

    private JobLocator jobLocator;

    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    public JobLauncherDetails() {
        System.out.println("JobLauncherDetails initialize...");
    }

    public void setJobLocator(JobLocator jobLocator) {
        this.jobLocator = jobLocator;
    }

    public void setJobLauncher(JobLauncher jobLauncher) {
        this.jobLauncher = jobLauncher;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) {
        System.out.println("executeInternal...");
        Map<String, Object> jobDataMap = context.getMergedJobDataMap();

        String jobName = (String) jobDataMap.get(JOB_NAME);

        JobParameters jobParameters = getJobParametersFromJobMap(jobDataMap);

        try {
            jobLauncher.run(jobLocator.getJob(jobName), jobParameters);
        } catch (JobExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // get params from jobDataAsMap property, job-quartz.xml
    private JobParameters getJobParametersFromJobMap(
            Map<String, Object> jobDataMap) {

        JobParametersBuilder builder = new JobParametersBuilder();

        for (Entry<String, Object> entry : jobDataMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            if (value instanceof String && !key.equals(JOB_NAME)) {
                builder.addString(key, (String) value);
            } else if (value instanceof Float || value instanceof Double) {
                builder.addDouble(key, ((Number) value).doubleValue());
            } else if (value instanceof Integer || value instanceof Long) {
                builder.addLong(key, ((Number) value).longValue());
            } else if (value instanceof Date) {
                builder.addDate(key, (Date) value);
            } else {
                // JobDataMap contains values which are not job parameters
                // (ignoring)
            }
        }

        // need unique job parameter to rerun the same job
        builder.addDate("run date", new Date());

        return builder.toJobParameters();

    }

}
```

In this case, the writer.... in write method is not printed.. Couldn't find the problem up till now..

Comment: Is job started from scheduler?

Comment: ya. It started in the JobLauncherDetails.java class

Answer (score 0):

I tried your config with latest version of batch (2.2.1.RELEASE), spring (3.2.3.RELEASE) and quartz (2.2.0) and all works fine substituting `file:input/report.csv` with `file:${user.dir}/src/main/java/input/report.csv`.
Are you sure file exists and doesn't throw a

> IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in
>   'strict' mode): URL [file:input/report.csv]

You can try use `classpath:input/report.csv` or build the real path of file (or check if your file is not empty...)